# Redirect paths in .htaccess AND 410 everything else

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a list of about 15 paths that I want to permanently redirect to a new domain, including the homepage.

However, I want everything else not in this list to 410 (gone). Is this possible in .htaccess without listing *all* other URLs/Paths?

```
RewriteRule ^category1\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category2\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category3\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category4\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category5\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category6\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category7\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category8\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category9\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category10\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category11\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category12\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category13\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category14\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category15\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the following *after* the existing redirects to serve a 410 Gone for everything else:

```
# 401 Gone for everything else
RewriteRule . - [G]
```

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteRule ^category1\*$  https://NEWSITE.com/ [R=301,L]
> ```

This regex does not look correct. That `\*` near the end of the regex is a literal `*`, so this only redirects `/categeory1*` (literal string). Is that the intention?

Maybe you mean `^category1/.*$`? Which is the same as `^category1/`. And matches any URL-path that starts `/catgeory1/`. (?)

Comment: Thank you. No, the intention is everything within this path. Is this correct (no backslash, no dollar sign):

^/category1*

Comment: @Mark See my updated answer. In that case it should just be `^category1` (or `^category1/` to match the complete path segment). There is no slash prefix on the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` directive in `.htaccess`. The `*` quantifier is a special regex meta character meaning 0 or more of the preceding token. It is not a "wildcard" character meaning any number of characters.